# get value of child element jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div id="knowledgeDomain" data-name="Page Field: Knowledge Domain">
<span title="Learning ＆ Development">Learning ＆ Development</span>
</div>
```

How do I get the "Learning ＆ Development" text using jQuery? Not the title...

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can try using jQuery('#knowledgeDomain span').text() or jQuery('#knowledgeDomain span').html()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('div#knowledgeDomain').children('span').text();
```

This will grab the text within the child span of #knowledgeDomain.

Here's a more full code example

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var results = $('div#knowledgeDomain').children('span').text();
     alert(results);
 });
 </script>
```

And here's the corresponding html

```
 <div id="knowledgeDomain" data-name="Page Field: Knowledge Domain">
     <span title="Learning ＆ Development">Learning ＆ Development</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using first child function:

```
$('#knowledgeDomain').first().html()
```